# blender script startup fail

Tags: scripting, export, linux

I wrote an exporter script and put the files into  `~/.config/blender/x.xx/scripts/addons/export` However, when I check the User Preferences I cannot find my script in the Import-Export section, so I could enable it. If I load the script [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604548/running-python-script-in-blender), however, an export entry appears under the Export menu. My current goal is to simply have it show up in the User Preferences, the code is pretty much copy&pasted from other scripts.

`__init__.py`:

```
bl_info = {
  "name": "SCN format (.scn)",
  "author": "",
  "version": (0, 0, 1),
  "blender": (2, 77, 0),
  "location": "File > Import-Export > scn (.scn)",
  "description": "Export SCN",
  "warning": "",
  "wiki_url": "",
  "support": 'NONE',
  "category": "Import-Export"
}

if "bpy" in locals():
  import importlib
else:
  import bpy

from bpy.props import (
  BoolProperty,
  FloatProperty,
  StringProperty,
  EnumProperty,
  )

from bpy_extras.io_utils import (
  ImportHelper,
  ExportHelper,
  orientation_helper_factory,
  path_reference_mode,
  axis_conversion,
  )

IOOBJOrientationHelper = orientation_helper_factory("IOOBJOrientationHelper", axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')

class ExportSCN(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper, IOOBJOrientationHelper):
  """Save a SCN File"""

  bl_idname = "export_scene.scn"
  bl_label = 'Export SCN'
  bl_options = {'PRESET'}

  filename_ext = ".scn"
  filter_glob = StringProperty(
    default="*.scn",
    options={'HIDDEN'},
  )

  output_format = EnumProperty(
    name="Output Format",
    items=(
      ("CBOR", "CBOR", "Export as CBOR"),
      ("JSON", "JSON", "Export as JSON"),
    ),
    default="CBOR"
  )

  path_mode = path_reference_mode

  check_extension = True

  def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(self, "output_format")

  def execute(self, context):    
    return "FINISHED"

def menu_func_export(self, context):
  self.layout.operator(ExportSCN.bl_idname, text="SCN (.scn)")

def register():
  bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

  bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)

def unregister():
  bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

  bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

Comment: Did you save the user settings after you activated the addon? http://www.gamefromscratch.com/image.axd?picture=image_thumb_2524.png

Comment: i can't activate it, it does not show up, there's nothing in the console, if I load from the command line shell.

Comment: I see. Sounds like you're missing some of the required stuff for registering addons. Please have a look at the tutorial, and if you can post the script's code it could help debug the issue: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html

Comment: My pleasure, here's the code, pretty much copy&pasted, nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

If you come across a problem like this, the solution might be not to copy&paste from an existing exporter script, but to literally copy the directory of some such exporter into `.config/blender/x.xx/scripts/addons` and work on it from there. This seems to work, but the root cause was blender getting freaked out by my `bl_info` line. Specifically:

```
bl_info = {
...
"support": 'NONE',
...
}
```

freaked it out and omitting the line solved the issue.